# jQuery - replace attribute value with new value of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, separator, code-separation

I've this html markup:

```
<div class="item" path="asaa/basba/asbsaa"></div>
<div class="item" path="bsbab/gbfssv/vsaava"></div>
<div class="item" path="asbaba/bsaba/dfsavava"></div>
```

The important point is that each is different. I need to get this attributes with something like that that:

var title = $(this).attr('path');

Now I need to separate the attribute: I need only the content which is between the * and the *:

```
<div class="item" path="asaa/basba/*asbsaa*"></div>
<div class="item" path="bsbab/gbfssv/*vsaava*"></div>
<div class="item" path="asbaba/bsaba/*dfsavava*"></div>
```

Any ideas to do something like that? Thanks for answers!

Comment: can you use something like: 
var strArr = title.split("/");
var lastpart = strArr[strArr.length - 1];

Comment: Use `var title = $(this).attr('path').split('/')` and then the `title[2]`will contain what you need

Comment: @Viktor No that's almost hard coding. Getting last is a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the attribute of each element and then setting back the last part of it

```js
    $(".item").attr("path",function(){         
       return $(this).attr("path").split("/").pop();        
    })
    console.log($('body').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" path="asaa/basba/asbsaa"></div>
<div class="item" path="bsbab/gbfssv/vsaava"></div>
<div class="item" path="asbaba/bsaba/dfsavava"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typicall scenario where I would use the "data" tag

```
<div class="item" data-path="asaa/basba/asbsaa"></div>
```

script:

```
 $(".item").data("path").split("/").pop();
```

more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)